# FREEBSD: make install Unknown modifier 'u' Variable ALL_OPTIONS is recursive

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I am looking for a method to remove the make error message I am getting. Please let me know if there is any suitable solution. My uname -a returns the following:

```
FreeBSD SM2-BSD 6.3-RELEASE FreeBSD 6.3-RELEASE #0: Wed Jan 16 04:18:52 UTC 2008     root@dessler.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386
```

**UPDATE: My make command is running on my old linux machine which is of the same configuration as my new one, running FreeBSD 6.3. I am not getting any errors in that. I tried copying this make file to my new machine, but its still giving the same error.**

I have just done portsnap update and am facing an error whenever I am trying to do a make install in any of the ports packages. I am getting the following error

```
make install
Unknown modifier 'u'

Variable ALL_OPTIONS is recursive.
```

I have tried deleting the /usr/ports/Mk and /usr/ports/lang/tcl84 and doing portsnap fetch again as suggested in http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=32376 but I am getting the same error again.

I also tried copying a working make binary from my other machine and pasted it into /user/bin/make into my new machine but to no avail.

I have even tried downloading the Make files and installing them from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.82.tar.gz by running the following command in the extracted folder:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
make distclean
```

This is the output I have got while running the above commands were:

```
[root@SM2-BSD ~/stuff/make-3.82]# ./configure >> logfile
config.status: WARNING:  'po/Makefile.in.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
[root@SM2-BSD ~/stuff/make-3.82]# make >> logfile
In file included from glob.c:1377:
glob.c: In function `glob_in_dir':
glob.c:199: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_realloc' from incompatible pointer type
In file included from glob.c:812:
glob.c: In function `glob':
glob.c:199: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_realloc' from incompatible pointer type
In file included from glob.c:931:
glob.c:199: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_realloc' from incompatible pointer type
In file included from glob.c:987:
glob.c:199: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_realloc' from incompatible pointer type
[root@SM2-BSD ~/stuff/make-3.82]# make install >> logfile
```

And my logfile reads:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ar... ar
checking for perl... perl
checking build system type... i386-unknown-freebsd6.3
checking host system type... i386-unknown-freebsd6.3
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for strerror in -lcposix... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/local/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/local/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/local/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/local/bin/msgmerge
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for GNU gettext in libc... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking how to link with libiconv... /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
checking for GNU gettext in libintl... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking for GNU gettext in libc... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking how to link with libiconv... /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
checking for GNU gettext in libintl... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... external libintl
checking how to link with libintl... /usr/local/lib/libintl.so -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for library containing getpwnam... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking whether stat file-mode macros are broken... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/timeb.h usability... yes
checking sys/timeb.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timeb.h... yes
checking stdarg.h usability... yes
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for uintmax_t... yes
checking for nanoseconds field of struct stat.st_mtim... no
checking whether to use high resolution file timestamps... no
checking whether system uses MSDOS-style paths... no
checking for standard gettimeofday... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strndup... no
checking for mkstemp... yes
checking for mktemp... yes
checking for fdopen... yes
checking for fileno... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for sigsetmask... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for getgroups... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setegid... yes
checking for setlinebuf... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setregid... yes
checking for getrlimit... yes
checking for setrlimit... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for pipe... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strsignal... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for atexit... yes
checking whether bsd_signal is declared... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strcmpi... no
checking for strncmpi... no
checking for stricmp... no
checking for strnicmp... no
checking for working strcoll... yes
checking for working alloca.h... no
checking for alloca... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking whether closedir returns void... no
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for pstat_getdynamic... no
checking for kstat_open in -lkstat... no
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking whether getloadavg requires setgid... no
checking whether sys_siglist is declared... yes
checking whether _sys_siglist is declared... no
checking whether __sys_siglist is declared... no
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for wait3... yes
checking for union wait... no
checking for SA_RESTART... yes
checking for location of SCCS get command... get
checking if system libc has GNU glob... no; using local copy
checking if malloc debugging is wanted... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating glob/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating config/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating w32/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile
config.status: creating build.sh
make  all-recursive
Making all in glob
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT glob.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/glob.Tpo -c -o glob.o glob.c
mv -f .deps/glob.Tpo .deps/glob.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT fnmatch.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/fnmatch.Tpo -c -o fnmatch.o fnmatch.c
mv -f .deps/fnmatch.Tpo .deps/fnmatch.Po
rm -f libglob.a
ar cru libglob.a glob.o fnmatch.o 
ranlib libglob.a
Making all in config
Making all in po
Making all in doc
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT ar.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ar.Tpo -c -o ar.o ar.c
mv -f .deps/ar.Tpo .deps/ar.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT arscan.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/arscan.Tpo -c -o arscan.o arscan.c
mv -f .deps/arscan.Tpo .deps/arscan.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT commands.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/commands.Tpo -c -o commands.o commands.c
mv -f .deps/commands.Tpo .deps/commands.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT default.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/default.Tpo -c -o default.o default.c
mv -f .deps/default.Tpo .deps/default.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT dir.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dir.Tpo -c -o dir.o dir.c
mv -f .deps/dir.Tpo .deps/dir.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT expand.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/expand.Tpo -c -o expand.o expand.c
mv -f .deps/expand.Tpo .deps/expand.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/file.Tpo -c -o file.o file.c
mv -f .deps/file.Tpo .deps/file.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT function.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/function.Tpo -c -o function.o function.c
mv -f .deps/function.Tpo .deps/function.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT getopt.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/getopt.Tpo -c -o getopt.o getopt.c
mv -f .deps/getopt.Tpo .deps/getopt.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT getopt1.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/getopt1.Tpo -c -o getopt1.o getopt1.c
mv -f .deps/getopt1.Tpo .deps/getopt1.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT implicit.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/implicit.Tpo -c -o implicit.o implicit.c
mv -f .deps/implicit.Tpo .deps/implicit.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT job.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/job.Tpo -c -o job.o job.c
mv -f .deps/job.Tpo .deps/job.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT misc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/misc.Tpo -c -o misc.o misc.c
mv -f .deps/misc.Tpo .deps/misc.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT read.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/read.Tpo -c -o read.o read.c
mv -f .deps/read.Tpo .deps/read.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT remake.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/remake.Tpo -c -o remake.o remake.c
mv -f .deps/remake.Tpo .deps/remake.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT remote-stub.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/remote-stub.Tpo -c -o remote-stub.o remote-stub.c
mv -f .deps/remote-stub.Tpo .deps/remote-stub.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT rule.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/rule.Tpo -c -o rule.o rule.c
mv -f .deps/rule.Tpo .deps/rule.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT signame.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/signame.Tpo -c -o signame.o signame.c
mv -f .deps/signame.Tpo .deps/signame.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT strcache.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/strcache.Tpo -c -o strcache.o strcache.c
mv -f .deps/strcache.Tpo .deps/strcache.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT variable.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/variable.Tpo -c -o variable.o variable.c
mv -f .deps/variable.Tpo .deps/variable.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT version.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c -o version.o version.c
mv -f .deps/version.Tpo .deps/version.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT vpath.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/vpath.Tpo -c -o vpath.o vpath.c
mv -f .deps/vpath.Tpo .deps/vpath.Po
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DINCLUDEDIR=\"/usr/local/include\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./glob   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT hash.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hash.Tpo -c -o hash.o hash.c
mv -f .deps/hash.Tpo .deps/hash.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o make ar.o arscan.o commands.o  default.o dir.o expand.o  file.o function.o getopt.o  getopt1.o implicit.o job.o  main.o misc.o read.o remake.o  remote-stub.o rule.o signame.o  strcache.o variable.o version.o  vpath.o hash.o glob/libglob.a  /usr/local/li
b/libintl.so -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib   
Making install in glob
Making install in config
Making install in po
/bin/sh ../config/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share
installing be.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing da.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing de.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing es.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing fi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing fr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing ga.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing gl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing he.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing hr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing id.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing it.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing ja.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing ko.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing lt.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing nl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing pl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing pt_BR.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing ru.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing sv.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing tr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing uk.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing vi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
installing zh_CN.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo
if test "make" = "gettext-tools"; then  /bin/sh ../config/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/gettext/po;  for file in Makefile.in.in remove-potcdate.sin  quot.sed boldquot.sed en@quot.header en@boldquot.header insert-header.sin Rules-quot   Makevars.template; do  /usr/bin/i
nstall -c -m 644 ./$file  /usr/local/share/gettext/po/$file;  done;  for file in Makevars; do  rm -f /usr/local/share/gettext/po/$file;  done;  else  : ;  fi
Making install in doc
test -z "/usr/local/share/info" || ../config/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/share/info"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./make.info ./make.info-1 ./make.info-2 '/usr/local/share/info'
 install-info --info-dir='/usr/local/share/info' '/usr/local/share/info/make.info'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || config/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c make '/usr/local/bin'
test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man1" || config/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/share/man/man1"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 make.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research over the internet I could find the solution to the problem. Even though it is not a very clear explanation to the problem it does help in solving the problem.

The error only comes in FreeBSD 6.3 once you do a portsnap update. It is suggested that you run  the following command to check which ports need to be downgraded.

To find that out use

```
make -V ALL_OPTIONS
```

It will give you all the ports, usually there will be this port **/usr/ports/Mk** which needs to be downgraded.

This folder simply contains some bsd.*.mk files

Now to solve the problem you need to get the old ports folder and replace it with the current Mk. Folder. You can do that by copying it from some other FreeBSD 6.3 machine which has make running properly or on which portsnap update has not been run.

**UPDATE:** You can also download a working Mk folder from **http://cinto.in/Mk.tar**

Once your replace the **/usr/ports/Mk** folder with the old Mk folder, your make will start running properly.

Now you can go to any port folder and run make install and it will run as desired.

Comment: After copying the extracted files from above link I get lots of `"Makefile", line 56: Malformed conditional (${PORT_OPTIONS:` errors. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like your current portstree is incompatible with the `make` used in ancient FreeBSD 6.3. Your best bet is to upgrade to FreeBSD 8 or 9, i.e. one of the currently supported STABLE branches.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jens for the quick reply. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to the newer version of FREEBSD as it is my work machine, so I have to work on this only. Can you suggest any alternate solution ?

Comment: Short of updating the make utility itself, that are your options. Using a current portstree requires a current make utility.

Comment: you could try to just update the make utility. But then you are on a completely unsupported system

Comment: arved, the new make is "devel/bmake"? http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.stable/91782

Answer (score 2):

*Replace the **/usr/ports/Mk** not work for me*

The best way is run "sysinstall"

```
#sysinstall
```

then add ports to your freebsd again.(Do post-install configuration of FreeBSD -> Distribution -> ports)

install from FTP site

ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/amd64/6.3-RELEASE/

:)

Answer (score 1):

@ChooChu and @Jens 's amswer are correct,you have an old and unsupported FreeBSD release,and you may update the port tree,the newer port tree is not compatible with your current old release.

If you still want use this old stable release,the idea is that you can downgrade the port tree to its corresponding version,you can download the port tree from FreeBSD archive site(this url is valid only for the moment when this comment is posted,if not,you should google "freebsd archive") for your 6.3 release:
http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/6.3-RELEASE/ports/

Download two files to an non-usr directory(not under "/usr"):
install.sh
ports.tgz

then switch to root and execute following cmds:

```
su
sh ./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in case when upgrading to supported FreeBSD Release is not an option:

> Edit file /usr/ports/Mk/bsd.options.mk (and, if needed, other files in /usr/ports/Mk/) removing all ":u" (case sensitive, without quotes) from the file. "

It works for me.