# How to downgrade all ports on FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd, bsd

I have FreeBSD 7.2 on my server. Trying to install some archiver, I upgraded all ports with commands portsnap fetch, portsnap extract.

And now when I try to compile any program with make, I get a lot of errors:

```
Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 5546: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 6036: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 6036: Unexpected end of file in for loop.
```

I need just to downgrade all ports to previous version.

Comment: Upgrading of BSD is not an option =(

Comment: 7.2 is not supported by the ports tree anymore... Install the ports tree from the 7.2 install medium.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found similar solution a bit earlier.

Comment: Note that this old ports tree *will* contain application versions that have known security vulnerabilities. As has the base OS. In general running an unsupported version of *any* OS is not a good idea, unless you can completely lock this machine off from access outside of your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution here - [FREEBSD: make install Unknown modifier 'u' Variable ALL_OPTIONS is recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563880/freebsd-make-install-unknown-modifier-u-variable-all-options-is-recursive)

Just replaced /usr/ports/Mk/* with original files, downloaded from ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/amd64/your version of FreeBSD/

As far as I understood Roland Smith had suggested same thing.